# Android: Quality loss when downscaling Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I'm getting an image (.png) from SQLiteDatabase and using this code to decode the bytearray into a bitmap:

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = true;
options.inScaled = true;
options.inDensity = 240;
options.inTargetDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAsBytes), null, options);
```

As you can see, image (3) should be like (2), but it doesn't.

1) [image: Original] = Image with no scale (metrics.densityDpi = 240);

2) [image: From drawable resource] = same .png above, but compiled in res/drawable;

3) [image: From downscale] = Image with down scale (with metrics.densityDpi = 120);

I also tried `options.inDither = false;`, but I see no difference.

So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: 1 and 3 look blurry, only 2 looks pretty alright. Thought I'd opine.

Comment: That's the point! Why images from resources are alright and images from bitmapfactory.decodestream look blurry?

Comment: You said 2 and 3 were blurry, but I'm seeing 1 and 3 blurry. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: What I mean is (3) should be like (2), but it does not. I'll "fix" my question anyway.

Comment: did you tried: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferQualityOverSpeed

Comment: @Marek R: I can't use it. It's only available in API 10.

Answer (score 0):

There a few other things I would try:

1. Load the png with no scale, when you come to draw the Image (either from within an ImageView or directly onto the canvas) set a [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to scale the image
2. Alternatively, load the image in the required density and try drawing the Bitmap directly to the canvas with a [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object. After instantiating your Paint, enable Bitmap filtering (this will increase the image quality)

   ```
   setFilterBitmap(true)
   ```
3. Finally, you could always load the Bitmap (density independent) and resize the Bitmap manually using [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29), make sure you set the third paramenter to true (this enabled bitmap filtering for increased quality). Below is an example of scaling a bitmap where 100 is the desired size:

   ```
   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap ( original_bitmap, 100, 100, true);
   ```

Comment: what if I download from the internet, and wish to avoid creating extra bitmaps ? Is it possible to downscale the bitmap from the beginning to the size i want (exact size of the imageView), and have the quality not being reduced?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, the best quality downscaling algorithm consists of 2 steps:

1. downscale using ***BitmapFactory.Options::inSampleSize->BitmapFactory.decodeResource()*** as close as possible to the resolution that you need but not less than it
2. get to the exact resolution by downscaling a little bit using ***Canvas::drawBitmap()***

Here is detailed explanation how SonyMobile resolved this task: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Here is the source code of SonyMobile scale utils: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/image-scaling-code-example-for-android/